# Difference between Install and Register verbs in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

[Approved Verbs for Windows PowerShell Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx) has the following:

1. **Install:** Places a resource in a location, and optionally initializes it.
2. **Register:** Creates an entry for a resource in a repository such as a database.

But what's the difference between a location and a repository in this context?

E.g. `Install` [page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.verbslifecycle.install(v=vs.85).aspx) has an `InstallServiceCommand` as an example -- but if it is something like `sc create` or `installutil`, it would only register a service, not actually copy anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Install` should be used when you're putting something in place, and when you're done, that resource is ready to be used and/or executed, e.g. a website, software package, etc.

`Register` should be used when you're telling another system about a new resource that is available, and that system is responsible for using/executing that resource.

This can be somewhat confusing because typically installing something will also register it in some way, which is what is happening in your example. Although `sc create` or `installutil` does register a new service with Windows, you still have to put the service binary somewhere, give it permissions, install a service user (if applicable), etc. So it is more correct to say you are installing a service than registering it.

If you had a system that monitored services, once you've installed it, you would then register that service with the monitoring software.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `Install-Module` (PowerShell V5) the location is the file system. In the case of `Register-PSSnapin`, the repo is the registry and in the case of Register-ObjectEvent it is a PowerShell internal data structure.  I would say `Install` typically refers to the filesystem where `Register` is a bit more varied in terms of what the repo can be.